# Перенос строки textarea в ipad(safari)

Tags: html, ipad, textarea, safari

Не работает перенос строки в textarea в ipad(safari), по-разному пробовал.

```
 1. \r\n
 2. \n
 3. PHP_EOL
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу найти.

Comment: Удалось решить вопрос? У меня тоже не работает, если в textarea добавляется текст через js, то символы переноса игнорируются. Такое поведение только на яблочных продуктах в сафари.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/hafzd5g5/1/

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;
  height: 8em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Вообще-то
всё
работает.

И было бы странно, если бы это было не так.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте простым переносом строки в самом коде:

```
<textarea placeholder="string1
string2"/>
```

Совсем не лаконично, но работать должно

Comment: Вот не пойму, откуда взялся placeholder? В вопросе же про него ничего нет...

Comment: @Qwertiy Прошу прощения, почему-то в голову закралась мысль о том что это было про placeholder. Но Ваш пример тоже должен работать. Единственное, где-то видел, что у Safari есть проблема с переносом в textarea. Если найду - скину ссылочку на это дело.

Comment: Мой работает - я проверял. Твой, вероятно, тоже.